# I have JavaScript menu code that is working but I don't know how to get the values into a form input field

Tags: javascript, html

I am not at all proficient in JavaScript. I have tried many ways to get the menu values into an html input form.

Here is the JavaScript and HTML code. I want the values to go into these input fields...

```js
function ShowHideDiv() {
  var options = document.getElementById("options");
  var requestName = document.getElementById("requestName");
  requestName.style.display = options.value == "Licensing" ? "block" : "none";
  requestName1.style.display = options.value == "Reporting" ? "block" : "none";
  requestName2.style.display = options.value == "Specification / Compatibility" ? "block" : "none";
  requestName3.style.display = options.value == "Operation / How To" ? "block" : "none";
  requestName4.style.display = options.value == "Installation / Uninstallation" ? "block" : "none";
  requestName5.style.display = options.value == "Upgrade / Downgrade" ? "block" : "none";
  requestName6.style.display = options.value == "Configuration / Workflow" ? "block" : "none";
  requestName7.style.display = options.value == "Administration" ? "block" : "none";
  requestName8.style.display = options.value == "Ordering / Replacing" ? "block" : "none";
  requestName9.style.display = options.value == "Documentation" ? "block" : "none";
  requestName10.style.display = options.value == "Security / Vulnerabilities" ? "block" : "none";
  requestName11.style.display = options.value == "Training" ? "block" : "none";
  requestName12.style.display = options.value == "Testing" ? "block" : "none";
}

var requestTypes = {
  'Licensing': ["Request", "Reset", "Renewal", "Upgrade / Downgrade", "Transfer", "How-To"],
  'Reporting': ["Creation", "Modification"],
  'Specification / Compatibility': ["NA"],
  'Operation / How To': ["Administration", "User assistance"],
  'Installation / Uninstallation': ["NA"],
  'Upgrade / Downgrade': ["Software Request"],
  'Configuration / Workflow': ["Modification", "Creation"],
  'Administration': ["NA"],
  'Ordering / Replacing': ["NA"],
  'Documentation': ["NA"],
  'Security / Vulnerabilities': ["NA"],
  'Training': ["NA"],
  'Testing': ["NA"],
}

function changecat(value) {
  if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
  else {
    var catOptions = "";
    for (categoryId in requestTypes[value]) {
      catOptions += "<option value='" + requestTypes[value][categoryId] + "'>" + requestTypes[value][categoryId] + "</option>";
    }
    document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = catOptions;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="requestName" id="requestName" value=""></input>
<input type="hidden" name="requestTypes" id="requestTypes" value=""></input>
```

Comment: Can you share some of the ways you've tried, along with a clear description of the expected behaviour?

Comment: You set the `.value` of the input, e.g. `document.getElementById("requestName").value = something;`